# How to remove an item from a list with enumeration starting at one?

Tags: python, input

```
if main == 'remove':
    for count, item in  enumerate(grocery_list, 1):
        print(f'{count}. {item}')
    which_item = input('Which item do you want to remove? Type in the name of the item please! ')
    del grocery_list[int(which_item-1)]
    print('Your item has been removed! ')
    continue
```

I'm trying to let user remove an item by typing in the enumerated index. When they do type in remove, it give them a list like this:

1. item
2. item
3. item

I tried to do `del grocery_list[int(which_item-1)]` but that gave an error. I want one subtracted from the which_item variable.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If position of item is asked to the user:

```
if main == 'remove':
    for count, item in enumerate(grocery_list, 1):
        print(f'{count}. {item}')
    which_item = int(input('Which item do you want to remove? Type in the position of the item please! '))
    grocery_list.pop(which_item-1)
    print('Your item has been removed! ')
```

If value of item is asked to the user:

```
if main == 'remove':
    for count, item in enumerate(grocery_list, 1):
        print(f'{count}. {item}')
    which_item = input('Which item do you want to remove? Type in the name of the item please! ')
    grocery_list.remove(which_item)
    print('Your item has been removed! ')
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly your user input value which_item may raise an error during conversion into int. so keep that inside a try except block

second why would you display your items line by line and ask user what to delete before all items have even been shown? separate both of the processes

here is the complete code

```
grocery_list=['item1','item2','item3','item4']
#initial display of list
for count,item in enumerate(grocery_list,1):
    print(f'{count}.{item}')

while True:
    try:
        which_item = int(input('Which item do you want to remove? Type in the name of the item please! '))
        del grocery_list[int(which_item-1)]
        print('Your item has been removed! ','current list')
        for count,item in enumerate(grocery_list,1):print(f'{count}.{item}')
    except:
        break
```

Comment: Just a bare `except` clause when an error is raised? Why not differentiate between an invalid argument or an empty list? You can also get rid of code duplication by only printing the list at the start of the `try` block.